# Overlapping text of CSS aligned elements

Tags: html, css, css-position

The following is **CSS** & **HTML** code that I was working on but for some reasons all the text is *overlapping* on each other (are not in proper position). I don't have a clue of what I am doing wrong here writing this code. I think maybe this is happening because of alignment of this menu-item. Thanks for helping me in advance.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fc354c, #0abfbc);
}

.menu-toggler {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-toggler:hover+label,
.menu-toggler:hover+label:before,
.menu-toggler:hover+label:after {
  background: white;
}

.menu-toggler:checked+label {
  background: transparent;
}

.menu-toggler:checked+label:before,
.menu-toggler:checked+label:after {
  top: 0;
  width: 40px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.menu-toggler:checked+label:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-toggler:checked+label:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(60deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(120deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(240deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(300deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item a {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.menu-toggler+label {
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transition: transform 0.5s, top 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.menu-toggler+label:before,
.menu-toggler+label:after {
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transition: transform 0.5s, top 0.5s;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.menu-toggler+label:before {
  top: 10px;
}

.menu-toggler+label:after {
  top: -10px;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(1) a {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(2) a {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(3) a {
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(4) a {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(5) a {
  transform: rotate(-240deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(6) a {
  transform: rotate(-300deg);
}

.menu-item {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu-item a {
  display: block;
  width: 520px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: Courgette;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.menu-item a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  color: white;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  font-size: 34.4444444444px;
}
```

```html
<body translate="no">
  <nav class="menu">
    <input checked="checked" class="menu-toggler" id="menu-toggler" type="checkbox">
    <label for="menu-toggler"></label>
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

My desired output is like this:

[image]

Comment: What is the proper position? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: I don't know the position because I taken this code from codepen.io

Comment: What is your desired output layout /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text boxes are too big and it doesn't have enough space to expand so it is overlapping. You can try to make it bigger by setting:

```
.menu-item {
   width: 300px;
   height: 560px;
}
```

Working example:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fc354c, #0abfbc);
}

.menu-toggler {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-toggler:hover+label,
.menu-toggler:hover+label:before,
.menu-toggler:hover+label:after {
  background: white;
}

.menu-toggler:checked+label {
  background: transparent;
}

.menu-toggler:checked+label:before,
.menu-toggler:checked+label:after {
  top: 0;
  width: 40px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.menu-toggler:checked+label:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-toggler:checked+label:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(60deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(120deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(240deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(300deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item a {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.menu-toggler+label {
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transition: transform 0.5s, top 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.menu-toggler+label:before,
.menu-toggler+label:after {
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transition: transform 0.5s, top 0.5s;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.menu-toggler+label:before {
  top: 10px;
}

.menu-toggler+label:after {
  top: -10px;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(1) a {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(2) a {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(3) a {
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(4) a {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(5) a {
  transform: rotate(-240deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(6) a {
  transform: rotate(-300deg);
}

.menu-item {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 700px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu-item a {
  display: block;
  width: 520px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: Courgette;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.menu-item a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  color: white;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  font-size: 34.4444444444px;
}
```

```html
<body translate="no">
  <nav class="menu">
    <input checked="checked" class="menu-toggler" id="menu-toggler" type="checkbox">
    <label for="menu-toggler"></label>
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

If you can change the width and height of individual options, It might look even better.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fc354c, #0abfbc);
}

.menu-toggler {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-toggler:hover+label,
.menu-toggler:hover+label:before,
.menu-toggler:hover+label:after {
  background: white;
}

.menu-toggler:checked+label {
  background: transparent;
}

.menu-toggler:checked+label:before,
.menu-toggler:checked+label:after {
  top: 0;
  width: 40px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.menu-toggler:checked+label:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-toggler:checked+label:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(60deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(120deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(240deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(300deg) translateX(-110px);
}

.menu-toggler:checked~ul .menu-item a {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.menu-toggler+label {
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transition: transform 0.5s, top 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.menu-toggler+label:before,
.menu-toggler+label:after {
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transition: transform 0.5s, top 0.5s;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.menu-toggler+label:before {
  top: 10px;
}

.menu-toggler+label:after {
  top: -10px;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(1) a {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(2) a {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(3) a {
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(4) a {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(5) a {
  transform: rotate(-240deg);
}

.menu-item:nth-child(6) a {
  transform: rotate(-300deg);
}

.menu-item {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 225px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu-item a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: Courgette;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.menu-item a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  color: white;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  font-size: 34.4444444444px;
}
```

```html
<body translate="no">
  <nav class="menu">
    <input checked="checked" class="menu-toggler" id="menu-toggler" type="checkbox">
    <label for="menu-toggler"></label>
    <ul>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a target="_blank">Company Goal</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Can space between 2 company goals can be lesser. How can I removed the space between 2 company goals?

Comment: @RadhikaVasudeva If we do then they will overlap, you can see the second code block with lesser widths which occupy lesser space.